# Docker GUI-mini: "AttributeError: 'ContainerCollection' object has no attribute 'remove'"

Tags: python, docker, flask

Приложение docker GUI-mini на Python. Контейнер создаетя, но при удалении - ошибка:

> AttributeError: 'ContainerCollection' object has no attribute 'remove'

Код Python:

```
import docker  
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, flash, redirect  
app = Flask(__name__)  
@app.route('/')  
def index():  
    client = docker.from_env()  
    lists = client.containers.list(all=True)  
    return render_template('index.html', lists=lists)  
@app.route('/create')  
def create():  
    client = docker.from_env()  
    client.containers.create(image='hello-world')  
    return render_template('index.html')  
@app.route('/delete')  
def delete(container_id=None):  
    client = docker.from_env()  
    client.containers.remove(container_id, force=True)  
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Фрагмент HTML:

```
{% for item in lists %} <tr><td><h4>{{ item['name'] }}</h4></td>
 <td><h4>{{ item['short_id'] }}</h4></td>
 <td> <a href="/delete"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Delete</button></a></td> </tr>
{% endfor %} </tbody>  </table>
<a class="nav-link" href="/create"><button class="btn btn-secondary">add_container</button></a>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Судя по [документации](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/3.5.0/pdf/), метод `remove` есть только у объекта `Container`, а у `ContainerCollection` его нет.
Видимо, надо делать так:

```
client.containers.get(container_id).remove(force=True)
```

Comment: Опередили с ответом насчет документации и метода `remove`, но я раньше добавил пример :D

Comment: @gil9red Такой вот `race condition` )  Я просто долго искал метод `get` в доке ))

Answer (score 1):

Погуглил по `docker-py` и, действительно, у объектов типа [ContainerCollection](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/blob/6367bbee2eb015387b918b9e24221fda0f557234/docker/models/containers.py#L515) нет метода `remove`, но оно есть у типа [Container](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/blob/6367bbee2eb015387b918b9e24221fda0f557234/docker/models/containers.py#L17).

Думаю, правильно будет так:

```
client.containers.get(container_id).remove(force=True)
```

Comment: изменив идёт другая ошибка `docker.errors.NullResource: Resource ID was not provided` разные вариаты https://github.com/docker/docker-py/blob/6367bbee2eb015387b918b9e24221fda0f557234/docs/containers.rst не помогают (код если удалить все контейнеры client.containers.prune() - срабатывает)

Comment: Судя по месту возникновения ошибки (https://github.com/docker/docker-py/blob/5a85cad54785bae45787b2584476c286301329e2/docker/utils/decorators.py#L17) это ошибка не возникает не в `client.containers.get(container_id).remove(force=True)`, правильно? Сложно что то вам сказать, когда непонятно откуда ошибка возникает, поэтому прикладывайте трассу стека :) Но если вам помог [prune_containers](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/blob/2c522fb362247a692c0493f0b47a33988eb2f3e3/docker/api/container.py#L967), то это круто :)